# Setting a object array to a state variable in React

Tags: reactjs, state

I am having a problem of updating a state array variable. I have looked fro many resources but none was worked.

> I have *Updated* the code to view the full architecture of how the
>   methods are linked to one another

This is how i defined the array in the state initially.

```
   constructor(props) {
         super(props);

         this.state = {
          test:[]
         }
       }
```

This is the render method. inside render method i have called to **getQuizView()** method

```
   render(){
        return ( 
          <div> 
            {this.getQuizView()}
          </div> 
        )
      }
```

and inside **getQuizView()** method i have called to my **updateArray()** method

```
  getQuizView(){
  return (
        <div>
          {this.updateArray()}
        </div>        
  )
}
```

The following method (updateArray()) is used to update the state variable.

```
updateArray(){
     for(var i=0; i<this.props.questions.length;i++){
      this.setState({ test: [...this.state.test, {id: this.props.questions[i].questionId, active: '0'}] })
    }
}
```

But it seems like **setState** is happening infinitely. but **this.props.questions.length = 34**

Comment: You should only be updating the state once (without a loop). Can you edit into your question the contents of `this.props.questions`?

Comment: where are you calling the updateArray() function?

Comment: Can you paste full code here or setup fiddler/codesandbox

Comment: @TiisetsoTjabane i am calling to the updateArray() function inside another function but that function has been called inside render method.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it goes into inifite loop because you are doing setState in for loop never do that. What you can do is take a local array variable and assign it with this.state.test array and push objects into it. Finally do the setState outside for loop.

You can try below code to avoid infinite loop.

```
  updateArray(){
       const questions = this.state.test;
       for(var i=0; i<this.props.questions.length;i++){
            questions.push({'id': this.props.questions[i].questionId, 'active': '0'});
      }
     this.setState({
         test: questions
    });
  }
```

You can even Do the same with map or forEach instead of for loop

Using .forEach:

```
updateArray(){
   const questions = this.state.test;
   this.props.questions.forEach(item => {
        questions.push({'id': item.questionId, 'active': '0'});
  });
 this.setState({
     test: questions
});
}
```

Using .map:

```
 updateArray(){
   const questions = this.props.questions.map(item => {    
             const object = {'id': item.questionId, 'active': '0'};
             return obj;
       });
  const allQuestions = [...this.state.test, questions];
  this.setState({
     test: allQuestions
  });
}
```

The difference between forEach and map is, forEach doesn’t return new array whereas map returns a new array

Comment: Don't forget the existing values in `this.state.test` should be included in `setState` as well.

Comment: Fixed your `map` example to properly use `map` instead of copy-pasting `forEach` :)

Comment: The map should happen on this.props.questions but not on this.state.test. Am I right?

Comment: @Sulthan the previous test array values also needed and we need to do map on this.props.questions but you did map on this.state.test. Please feel to edit my answer if you have solution for map on questions and also the newly returned array of map should keep existing array values as well. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Well, you are correct but in that case, `map` should not be used at all. If you are not using the return value of `map`, don't use `map`. You are still using it like a `forEach`. Probably could be something like: `const newQuestions = this.state.test.map(question => ({ ... })); const questions = [...this.state.test, ...newQuestions];`

Comment: @Sulthan you still doing map on test instead of props.questions. I updated my answer for map and combined two arrays as you suggested :) please have a look

Comment: @Think-Twice Yes, that would work :) I am not sure the OP actually wants o merge two arrays, maybe he just wants to create a new array from `props.questions`. Hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are updating the state in the `render()` method. The render method is not supposed to have side effects, it must be purely for "rendering" your DOM.

The way react works is that whenever you update the state outside the `constructor()` it calls the render method, just look at the life cycle diagram [image: react life cycle]

This is a good source [React component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

What you are doing is while rendering you update the state(updateArray()) which in turn will cause the render function to be called again then the render function will update the state(updateArray()) and it results in an infinite loop.

[render]-> [update state(updateArray())] -> render -> [update state].....

Just remove the `updateArray()` method from the render to the other life cycle hooks like `componentDidMount()`

if you want to show the questions just update `getQuizView`

```
   getQuizView(){
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.questions.map((val)=>{
               <div>val</div>
                 })
           }
        </div>        
      )
  }
```